# Why does the chrome browser console forcibly coerce a string to a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

noob question. I'm learning 'You don't know JS' and I struck this anomaly on page 11:

```
var a = "42";
var b = Number( a );

console.log( a ); // "42"
console.log( b ); //  42
```

Now I do get that behaviour if I run it in JS Bin.
But in the latest Chrome browser console which I'm learning with, I get this unexpected behaviour:

```
var a = "42";
var b = Number(a);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
42              // no quotes?
42
< undefined
```

And trying manual coercion from a number to a string, also an unexpected result:

```
a = 42;
b = a.toString();
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
42      
42            // no quotes?
< undefined
```

Can anyone shed some light on this behaviour please? I have googled it and come up short, cheers.

Comment: Why should `console.log` print quotes? [No](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP11DKVFJ8/9/AA).

Comment: look at the **colour** of the output to determine the type - though it does mean you have to remember colours - and in my chrome, it's not that obvious

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686625/how-to-force-console-log-to)? / "`console.log` isn't necessarily consistent across browsers"

Comment: Have you tried logging a string that doesn't contain numbers? `console.log("foo")` for example.

Comment: This is how the JS Bin console interprets the same code:
var b = "42";
undefined
console.log(b);
"42"                   <= quotes
undefined

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the values aren't printed with quotes around them is due to the fact that the string doesn't contain any quotes **as its content**. So, you shouldn't expect quotes to be produced unless that were the case.

To remove any doubt, you can always check the type with **[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**:

```js
var a = "42";
var b = Number(a);
var c = '"String with quotes as part of the content."';
var d = 'String with NO quotes as part of the content.';

console.log(a, typeof a);
console.log(b, typeof b);
console.log(c, typeof c);
console.log(d, typeof d);
```

Keep in mind that the way a particular browser decides to implement their `console` behavior is entirely up to them. There are no standards on this since `console` is not a part of JavaScript. So, it's entirely normal find differences between one client and another in that regard. What's important is that the JavaScript runtime process the data according to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the console you'll notice slight colour difference when logging it out.

[A number will be blue whereas a string will be black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJeaa.jpg)

If you don't want unexpected coercions just use `===` when doing comparisons [or do what Scott Marcus suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49733231/5122821).

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I had the font too small to notice any colour difference, plus hadn't used the chrome console before.
That's quite a well known book, any idea why it works in JS Bin as the book states (with quotes), and displays differently in chrome? Has chrome always displayed like that?

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome console.log(..) output is always without quotes.
Try to see:

```
console.log("asd")
```

And try this in the console:

```
var a = "42";
a;
```

Should return the wanted result.

Comment: Your "try this" block creates variable `a`, then `b` from `a` but then outputs `a` to the console.  Were you supposed to output `b` instead?  If not, then line 2 isn't serving any purpose.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh You're right, I removed the assignment from b. :)